# How can I perform this DAX formula?

Tags: powerbi, dax, aggregate, measure

I'm a beginner at DAX formula's; so my question is, how can I make my formula work? It says I have to use an aggregate function because the column 2016 is too big. But I want to use the unique percentages in 2016, so I can't use SUM.

```
Employment per km2 = CALCULATE(('Samenvoegen2'[2016] * 'geonames'[Population]) / 'geonames'[Area(in sq km)]).
```

The result would be a list of population amounts per km2. What happens if I use COUNT? Is there a way to measure what I want to measure without aggregate functions?

It says I had to use aggregate functions, but I'm not sure which one to use and how. Maybe I need to use a filter?

I expect a list of population per km2 amounts.

Comment: Please tell me how you formed your data model so that I can help you.  You have 2 tables: Samenvoegen2 and geonames. How are they related to each other ? Which one is fact table ? Which one is dimension table?

Comment: They are not related to eachother I think, one is a list with percentages for employment in population and one is population in amount. The third column is the area in km2.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking "across" your relationship to the 'geonames' table, you need to use an iterator ("x-function"), because you need the evaluation context from the related table.

```
CALCULATE(
SUMX('Samenvoegen2',
'Samenvoegen2'[2016] * RELATED('geonames'[Population]) / RELATED('geonames'[Area(in sq km)])
))
```